# how to create random dynamic links in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, random, hyperlink

Hi I am new to web dev world. I am trying to write a code where I can get dynamic links.

Like after the `?` in a url I want to generate random numbers so every time a user goes to the website it will make a call to the server and not use the cache.

Comment: `var href='http://aaa.bb.com/hello.php?name='+Math.random();` is this you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for your requirement would be to append system time in milli second instead of random number as random number can be the same.

You can use as -

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <a ng-href="url/?no={{time}}">link</a>
</div>

function Ctrl($scope)
{
    $scope.time = new Date().getTime();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs you can use nghref directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Something like this:

```
// html
<a ng-href="someurl/?rand={{getRand()}}">link</a>


// angular controller
$scope.getRand = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*100000)
}
```

Comment: If you find the answer useful consider voting it up instead of saying thanks :)